# Pre_get_post custom taxonomy combined with custom fields?

Tags: custom-taxonomy, custom-field, pre-get-posts

So I have the function below to filter posts by custom terms and custom fields.
The custom taxonomy filter works good. The custom field filter works as well, which actually shocked me, since I don't have any experience on this level. 
My question is: I am using `'compare'=>'LIKE',` for my custom fields and I was wondering if that is the best way to filter out posts, based on the CF values. Basically I would like to know if the function below is a proper way of filtering out posts, using the pre_get_posts function.
Any insights are greatly appreciated!

I have custom fields like this in my database:

```
Key: app_customers | Value: a:2:{i:0;s:11:"Private";i:1;s:8:"Business";}

key: app_utilities | Value: a:4:{i:0;s:12:"Own studio";i:1;s:14:"Mobile studio";i:2;s:9:"Makeup Artist";i:3;s:22:"Digital photo editing";}
```

Below my code for filtering.

```
<?php
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'rt_tax_archive' );
function rt_tax_archive($query) {
    if (is_admin()) {
        return; /* If we're in the admin panel - drop out */
    }
    global $wp_query;
    if ($query->is_main_query() && isset($_GET['ls'])) {
        //Get value
        $rt_cat_id = $_GET['listing_cat'];
        $rt_term_id_country = $_GET['listing_country'];
        $rt_field_id_customers = $_GET['listing_customers'];
        $rt_field_id_utilities = $_GET['listing_utilities'];

        //filter custom terms
        //Category filter
        if (isset($rt_cat_id) && !empty($rt_cat_id[0])) {
            $tax_query[] = array(
                'taxonomy' => 'listing_category',
                'field' => 'id',
                'terms' => array($rt_cat_id[0]),
            );
        }
        //country filter
        if (empty($_GET['listing_country']) && isset($rt_term_id_country) && !empty($rt_term_id_country[0])) {
            $tax_query[] = array(
                'taxonomy' => 'listing_country',
                'field' => 'id',
                'terms' => array($rt_term_id_country[0]),
            );
        }

        //Filter custom fields  
        //Customers
        if (isset($rt_field_id_customers) && !empty($rt_field_id_customers[0])) {
            $meta_query[] = array(
                    'key'=>'app_customers',
                    'value'=>$rt_field_id_customers[0],
                    'compare'=>'LIKE',
                );
        }
        //utilities
        if (isset($rt_field_id_utilities) && !empty($rt_field_id_utilities[0])) {
            $meta_query[] = array(
                    'key'=>'app_utilities',
                    'value'=>$rt_field_id_utilities[0],
                    'compare'=>'LIKE',
                );
        }

        //Set query only once per filter, to do proper filtering
        $query->set('tax_query', $tax_query);
        $query->set('meta_query', $meta_query);

    }
}

        ?>
```

Comment: `LIKE` is usefull when you use wildcard like "%studio" for values which ends with "studio". If you don't need this you can remove the key `compare` and then the query uses the default value `=` https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters

Comment: I do need the compare=>like i guess.. do the value have to end with "studio" or could the word studio be anywhere in the value?